# How to kill debugging session in Eclipse? Nothing shown in Debug view

Tags: eclipse

I have 2 versions of my app deployed on the cloud. They both have same address, but different cloud instance names.

I am able to debug one application from cloud, but when I try to connect to the other one, eclipse gives the error:

> Error launching a Cloud Debugging Session.
>   Server returned 409 (Conflict) for URL: 'address'
>
> Another debugging/profiling session to this application seems to be active.

There is no sessions available in Debug view. I even restarted eclipse and my machine.

Is there a way to kill all/any debugging/profiling sessions in eclipse?

I was able before to switch debugging from one cloud app to the other but today I get this issue.

Comment: In the _Debug_ view all connected sessions are shown and you can right-click and choose _Terminate/Disconnect All_.

Comment: @howlger sorry, I forgot to mention there is nothing shown in Debug view. Thanks for input

Comment: Another person might be currently connected to the application causing this error on your side.